# Debian - I have removed some of my man page files

Tags: debian, packages, man

I deleted the `/usr/share/man/man1` directory and wondered if there was a quick way to recover the manuals for the installed packages.

Comment: You should be able to re-install them with apt-get. You can try... sudo apt-get install man manpages.

Answer (score 0):

**Installing man page packages**

[According to here](http://dilanpersonal.blogspot.com/2007/10/getting-missing-man-pages-in-debian-new.html), you don't get a lot of man pages with the default Debian package selection. That guy said to run:

```
apt-get install manpages-dev
```

It looks like [this page](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=manpages) lists package names for various man page packages you can get.

**Meta Packages / reconfigure**

I'm generally an Ubuntu user over Debian, but they're quite related. For Ubuntu, I'd try something like:

```
dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop
```

In that case, 'ubuntu-desktop' in a meta package that defines the default packages to be installed with the desktop version of Ubuntu. There's got to be some debian equivalant.. perhaps "debian-desktop"? Maybe look in to that if you need to.

Good luck! Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry about the tardy reply running 'mandb' seemed to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to restore all of those files will be to re-install any packages that had files installed there.

This command will show you a list of installed packages with files that belong in that directory:

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man1
```

Then you can re-install those (or just the ones you care about) with:

```
aptitude reinstall <package name(s)>
```